# How do I enable XSLT extension for PHP 5?

Tags: php

How can I get PHP's LibXML module with the XSLT extension enabled (--with-xsl)?

What are the steps involved in installing XSLT and from where I can download it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a package manager like `yum` or `apt`, try a search for `libxslt` and confirm that the package is installed.

If you installed the [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) library yourself, use `--with-xsl=/path/to/libxslt` as described in the PHP manual's [XSL Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php) instructions.